# Make completing-read respect sorting order of a collection

Tags: completion, sorting, completing-read

Either:

```
(completing-read "test: " '("a" "b" "c"))
```

or:

```
(completing-read "test: " '("c" "b" "a"))
```

produces the same result in completion buffer when pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>. How do I make it respect the sorting order?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info - the `elisp` tag has a specific meaning and it should be used *very rarely*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The sorting order in the *Completions* list is determined by the `display-sort-function` property of your completion table (as returned by `completion-metadata`).  In your case, your completion table has no such property, so it falls back to the default, which is to sort alphabetically.

You can use:

```
(defun my-presorted-completion-table (completions)
  (lambda (string pred action)
    (if (eq action 'metadata)
        `(metadata (display-sort-function . ,#'identity))
      (complete-with-action action completions string pred))))
```

and then

```
(completing-read "test: " (my-presorted-completion-table '("a" "b" "c")))
```

[ This assumes you're using `lexical-binding`.  ]

Comment: If you want `icomplete` to also respect the order, you can add a `(cycle-sort-function . ,#'identity)` to the metadata list.

Comment: I needed to use `reverse` instead of `identity` to display the list in the original order!  Why?  (24.3.1)

Comment: @JohnH.: Sounds like a bug (in 24.3).  If you can reproduce the problem in Emacs-27, you might want to report it as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Give `completing-read` a list of lists, and it will respect the order:

```
(completing-read "test: " '(("a") ("b") ("c")))
(completing-read "test: " '(("c") ("b") ("a")))
```

The docstring says:

> `(completing-read PROMPT COLLECTION &optional PREDICATE`
>   `REQUIRE-MATCH INITIAL-INPUT HIST DEF INHERIT-INPUT-METHOD)`
>
> Read a string in the minibuffer, with completion.
>   PROMPT is a string to prompt with; normally it ends in a colon and a space.
>   COLLECTION can be a list of strings, an alist, an obarray or a hash table.
>   ...

It can therefore take an alist as a collection.  In effect, you're creating an alist with keys but without values.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Emacs 27.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest not using this ancient spell.

The built-in `ido-completing-read` doesn't have this deficiency:

```
(ido-completing-read "test: " '("a" "b" "c"))
(ido-completing-read "test: " '("c" "b" "a"))
```

Neither does `helm`:

```
(helm :sources
      `((name . "test: ")
        (candidates . ("a" "b" "c"))))
(helm :sources
      `((name . "test: ")
        (candidates . ("c" "b" "a"))))
```

Comment: The problem with `ido-completing-read` is that it has weird newline character `^` from `semantic-format-tag-summarize`. As for Helm, I cannot assume everyone use it. That's why `completing-read` is the only option.

Comment: That's a lame reason not to use it. Just postprocess whatever `semantic-format-tag-summarize` gives you.

Comment: Or submit a bug report for `ido`

Comment: I did that as well but did not succeed. The output from `semantic-format-tag-summarize` returns something at the end, but the character is not displayed in `completing-read` or `helm-comp-read`. I already wrote another function in place of `semantic-format-tag-summarize`, without face yet. For displaying tags (with colors) to users, I still use `semantic-format-tag-summarize` but use a custom buffer with text widgets instead.

Comment: Probably I will submit bug to Ido after finding out what `semantic-format-tag-summarize` returns at the end. I had a solution but I still want to know a solution to `completing-read`. I know Helm can make it but just wanted to know if an easy way with `completing-read` exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then the order is respected by `completing-read`.

(And you can sort using [different sort orders](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Sorting_Candidates), either interactively or via Lisp. And unlike vanilla Emacs, sorting affects both `*Completions*` display and cycling order.)

Comment: Same as the comment in abo-abo's answer, I cannot rely on external packages. And `ido-completing-read` is having some problem.

Comment: Perhaps you cannot, but perhaps someone else can. ;-) This is a simple solution to the problem as posed: just use `completing-read` with Icicles. You can even just turn on `icicle-mode` temporarily (e.g. for the call to `completing-read`), using, e.g., macro `icicle-with-icy-mode-ON`.